# django migration createsuperuser

Tags: python, django

I wanted to create a superuser but everytime I run
 `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` it says `You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.`

Can you help me please?

I'm using Python 3 and Django 2.1.2

Comment: Well what is not clear about the error message? It is rather self-explaining, you should first migrate the database.

Answer (score 2):

run

```
python manage.py makemigrations $YOURNEWAPP
```

it will make an Object a new model you have had created

then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It will create and add the whole necessary tables to the Database